# SSL connection could not be established with Yelp API

Tags: ssl, httpclient, yelp, fusion

Attempting to make api calls to Yelp Fusion via .Net 5 API but receiving the following error:

> Error Message: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner
> exception. Source: System.Net.Http Trace:    at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore

Of course, the API call to Fusion from localhost runs fine. This appears to be a cipher issue??

Also, attempted to bypass the certificate with the following code:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => cert.Verify(); //{ return true; };

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler)) {....
```

Any insight on how to resolve would be greatly appreciated.